# Jenkins active choices plugin - how to get value of password parameter

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a parametrized jenkins job with 2 parameters:

- 1st job parameter is APIKEY of type 'Password parameter'
- 2nd job parameter is SERVICE of type 'Active Choices Reactive Parameter'  - single select, referencing parameter APIKEY and using following groovy script code which returns value of APIKEY parameter in the single select UI control:

  ```
  [ APIKEY ]
  ```

When I start the build of this job, value offered in single select UI control for parameter SERVICE is garbled (encrypted?) value of APIKEY.

What I want is to be able to use actual (decrypted) value of entered  APIKEY password parameter in the script code of SERVICE parameter.

I tried decrypting the APIKEY garbled value by using hudson.util.Secret like below but with no luck:

```
   def apikey = hudson.util.Secret.fromString(APIKEY).getPlainText()
```

Is there any way to get actual password parameter value from active choices reactive parameter groovy script code?

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit more trying this out it turns out this is working properly after all - but only when password parameter is entered manually, not with the default password parameter value (not sure if this is a bug or a feature).

First time the job is run default password parameter value provided is garbled, but entering the value again in the password field then gives the correct value in groovy script.

This worked for me:

1. run job build

   - at this point APIKEY value in groovy script code of the SERVICE field is not evaluated correctly - it is garbled value
2. enter correct value in APIKEY password parameter field - e.g. "abc123"
3. switch focus to SERVICE field
4. SERVICE field groovy code gets executed now and shows actual entered value of APIKEY: "abc123"

Since my use case is such that entering APIKEY is mandatory every time job is build this is good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old topic, but I found a solution so I'll add it here in case anyone else still needs it. This was working code, but I sanitized it for publication.

This Groovy script runs in an Active Choices Reactive Parameter. The task is to provide a list of the build versions available to deploy from an internal Artifactory archive. The API key needed for the REST call is stored as Secret Text in our Jenkins instance. So this code reads from the Credentials plugin's repo to find the secret text, then adds it to the header of the http request.

This is a clunky solution. There is much more elegant `withCredentials` method for Groovy, but it may only work in Jenkins pipelines. I didn't find a way to use it in this parameter.
This solution also does not use HTTPBuilder, which would have been simpler, but wasn't available in our Groovy plugin.

```js
import org.apache.http.client.methods.*
import org.apache.http.impl.client.*
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

def APP_FULL_NAME = "My.Project.Name"

def request = new HttpGet("https://fakeDns/artifactory/api/search/versions?r=releases&a="+APP_FULL_NAME)

def jenkinsCredentials = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
        com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.Credentials.class,
        Jenkins.instance,
        null,
        null
);
def apiKey
for (creds in jenkinsCredentials) 
{
  //println creds.id
  //println creds.class
  if(creds.id == "my_target_api_key")
  {
    apiKey = creds.secret.toString(creds.secret);
    break
  }
}
    
request.addHeader("X-API-KEY", apiKey)
def responseString = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(request, new BasicResponseHandler());
def branchList = new JsonSlurper().parseText(responseString)
//return branchList
def myList= []
branchList.results.each {  myList << it }
return myList.version
```